# SQL merge minimum time difference

Tags: sql, join, db2

I'm having trouble with a SQL statement that is a bit over my skill level. Running this in a DB2 datawarehouse.

I need to join two columns (CODE1 and CODE2) from TABLE2 into TABLE1 based on some IDs and the minimum time difference between a date in TABLE1 (STARTDATE) and a date in TABLE2 (TIME_SENT). The statement below shows what I'm trying to do, but having issues with ordering of `group by` and `having` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.ID1, B.ID2, D.CODE1, D.CODE2
           FROM TABLE1 B, TABLE2 D
           WHERE D.STATUS = '7'
           GROUP BY B.ID1, B.ID2
           HAVING ABS(B.STARTDATE - D.TIME_SENT) = MIN(ABS(B.STARTDATE - D.TIME_SENT)) TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.ID1 = TABLE2.ID1
AND TABLE1.ID2 = TABLE2.ID2;
```

Appreciate any help with this.

STRUCTURE TABLE1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| ID1 (VARCHAR) | ID2 (VARCHAR) | STARTDATE (TIMESTAMP) | 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

STRUCTURE TABLE2:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID1 (VARCHAR) | ID2 (VARCHAR) | TIME_SENT (TIMESTAMP) | STATUS (INTEGER) | CODE1 (VARCHAR) | CODE2 (VARCHAR) |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

STRUCTURE OUTPUT:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID1 (VARCHAR) | ID2 (VARCHAR) | STARTDATE (TIMESTAMP) | CODE1 (VARCHAR) | CODE2 (VARCHAR) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So `TABLE2` can have several different code pairs `(CODE1,CODE2)` per unique ID `(ID1,ID2)`, but I only want to keep the code pair where `TABLE2.TIME_SENT` is closest to `TABLE1.STARTDATE`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you would like to see as well as possibly a sample of the two tables contents and structure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can select CODE1 and CODE2 in your inner query since they're not in the group by or in an aggregate function. I think you need an inner query that just finds the minimum time difference for a given id pairing. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1 B
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 D
    ON B.ID1    = D.ID1
   AND B.ID2    = D.ID2
   AND D.STATUS = '7'
 WHERE D.ID1 IS NULL
    OR ABS(B.STARTDATE - D.TIME_SENT) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(E.STARTDATE - F.TIME_SENT))
                                           FROM TABLE1 E
                                          INNER JOIN TABLE2 F
                                             ON E.ID1    = F.ID1
                                            AND E.ID2    = F.ID2
                                            AND F.STATUS = '7'
                                          WHERE E.ID1 = B.ID1
                                            AND E.ID2 = B.ID2
                                          GROUP BY
                                                E.ID1
                                               ,E.ID2);
```

I'm assuming that you have some values in TABLE1 that don't have a match in TABLE2 but that you still want to be returned.